# How to send custom parameter and receive it in the custom application, microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have created a deeplink which redirects user from email to Microsoft teams application and points to my custom app and opens static tab.
This static tab hosts an angular application.
link looks like this : `'msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/xid/yid?threadId=testthread'`
I want to fetch this link and make use of **threadId**, which is not microsoft teams property. I am not able to catch this url, every time my app.component.ts loads, the url cached from window.location is of my application and not of the above link. Is there a way I can catch and store deeplink redirect url, as soon as the the application opens ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I have resolved this by using subEntityId, which can be caught by context inside page, it will be named in ts context as subPageId. You can pass any custom parameter inside this, only json format allowed.
To those who are searching, it is not possible to send custom param currently like how we send in the url using '?'. Not possible to catch this as you are loading the app from external source.

So using subEntityId fixes the problem.